# Why NodeJS promise.all running promise in sequential manner, instead concurrently

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have this NodeJS code and by running this I'm getting unexpected result, can anyone please help what I am doing wrong here?

```js
const process = require('process');

const COUNT = 5000000000;

async function cpu_bound_task(n) {
    let pid = process.pid;
    let processName = process.title;
    console.log(`${pid} * ${processName} ---> Start counting...`);
    while(n>0){
        n--;
    }
    console.log(`${pid} * ${processName} ---> Finished counting...`);
}

async function test_multithreading_for_cpu_bound_tasks() {
    console.log("Without multithreading...");
    let start = new Date();
    await cpu_bound_task(COUNT);
    await cpu_bound_task(COUNT);
    let end = new Date();
    console.log('Time taken in seconds -', (end - start)/1000);

    console.log("With multithreading...");
    start = new Date();
    await Promise.all([
        cpu_bound_task(COUNT),
        cpu_bound_task(COUNT)
    ]);
    end = new Date();
    console.log('Time taken in seconds -', (end - start)/1000);
}

test_multithreading_for_cpu_bound_tasks();
```

I am getting output like this:

```bash
Without multithreading...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
Time taken in seconds - 12.798
With multithreading...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
Time taken in seconds - 12.763
```

but I am expecting like this:

```bash
Without multithreading...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
Time taken in seconds - 12.798
With multithreading...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Start counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
6956 * Windows PowerShell ---> Finished counting...
Time taken in seconds - 12.763
```

One thing I can guess is when one thread is running it is occupying one entire cpu and second thread don't get a chance to acquire the cpu [but I have 2 cores (4 virtual cores)] and But if this so then why context switching is not happening?

[EDIT]: Added my other observation

If I change `cpu_bound_task` like this

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function cpu_bound_task(n) {
    const SLEEP = 1000*5;
    let pid = process.pid;
    let processName = process.title;
    console.log(`${pid} * ${processName} ---> Start sleeping...`);

    await sleep(SLEEP);
    console.log(`${pid} * ${processName} ---> Finished sleeping...`);
}
```

It will work as expected/

Comment: js is sngle threaded. you dont have any async code here

Comment: async does not mean multithreaded. JavaScript is single-threaded, and async is not intended for CPU-bound functions. You'll need to explicitly spawn another process to handle the CPU-bound function call concurrently.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts
Ok I agree with both of you but in Promise.all why second promise is waiting for first to be finished first, why is not starting immediately.

Comment: Because the single available thread is already busy with the first one.

Comment: `await` makes the thread available for other tasks, so while one promise sleeps, the other can carry on. Correct usage would be I/O bound like awaiting some AJAX request, for example doing that CPU-bound work on the server side while the client awaits the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that Nodejs runs your Javascript in a single thread.  So, the only ways that things can be run in truly parallel fashion are if the operations themselves are in a `WorkerThread` a child process or if the operations are truly asynchronous themselves (generally using other truly asynchronous APIs or native code in their implementation).

Second, remember that adding the `async` keyword to a function does not change whether it runs synchronously or not.  It makes the function return a promise, catches exceptions and allows you to use `await` inside the function, but doesn't change how the code in the function executes.

`Promise.all()` is a notification manager.  That's all it does.  You pass it an array of promises and it just tracks when they are all done and collects their resolved values.  It has absolutely nothing at all to do with how the individual operations are run.  In fact, your own code starts those operations first before you even have the promises that you pass to `Promise.all()`.

As such `Promise.all()` allows multiple asynchronous operations to be in flight at the same time and then it aggregates the results for you and tells you when they are all done.

It does NOT enable multiple synchronous operations to run in parallel.  That's just not what it does.

---

> Ok I agree with both of you but in Promise.all why second promise is waiting for first to be finished first, why is not starting immediately.

In this code of yours:

```
await Promise.all([
    cpu_bound_task(COUNT),
    cpu_bound_task(COUNT)
]);
```

What this does is run `cpu_bound_task(COUNT)` and wait for it to return and get the promise that it returns.  Then, run the 2nd `cpu_bound_task(COUNT)` and wait for it to return and get the promise that it returns.  Then, put both those promises into an array and pass that array to `Promise.all()`.  Then, `await` the promise that `Promise.all()` returns.

But, `cpu_bound_task(n)` is entirely synchronous.  Putting it in an `async` function doesn't change that.  So, it blocks and doesn't return its promise until it's done with all of its work.  So, the first one blocks, finishes, returns.  Then, the second one runs, blocks, finishes, then returns.  Then those two already resolved promises are passed to `Promise.all()`.  So, `Promise.all()` doesn't really have anything to do here because you're passing it two already resolved promises.

Comment: If you see my [EDIT] section in question, I've added second code where It worked as I expect, that code is also synchronous but here both runs together.

Comment: @AnkitKumar - In your edit, you made the modified `cpu_bound_task()` actually asynchronous.  It's no longer synchronous.  `await sleep(SLEEP);` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  `sleep()` immediately returns a promise and resolves it some time later.  `setTimeout()` inside of `sleep()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  It immediately returns and calls its callback sometime later.  That's completely different than your super long `while` loop in the first one.